# how to insert image in mysql using perl

Tags: mysql, perl

Please help me in inserting an image in mysql DB using perl.

This is my HTML Code:

```
<form name="addNewUser"  method="get" action="addNewUser.pl" >
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" value = ""></br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="pwd" value = ""></br>
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" ></br>
    Image:<input name="image" accept="image/jpeg" type="file"> </br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This is My perl Code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
#use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw/fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser/;
use CGI::Session ( '-ip_match' );
use HTML::Template;

# read the CGI params
my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $email = $cgi->param("email");
my $pwd = $cgi->param("pwd");
my $name = $cgi->param("name");
$filename = $cgi->param ("image");


require "dbconfig.pl";

$rows = $db_handle->do( "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('NULL','$name', '$email', '$pwd', '$image') " );
```

What is wrong in this? Its not loading the file in DB.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance, Sapna

Comment: first, remove the # from the use strict line and declare all variables with my. second, don't insert database values directly into the string (they might contain quotes, for example). see http://bobby-tables.com/ for a short intro to placeholders. third, which error message do you get?

Comment: Also, you should not save clear text passwords. You should hash them instead. You wouldn't like SO to save your password in a readable way so the admins could take a look at who uses the most funny password, would you?

Comment: Hi simbabque, I am using md5 for password encryption. Just for simplification i have removed it from the question in SOF. Can you please me, what wrong i am doing here, so i am not able to store the image in DB.

Comment: I suppose that your image field is longblog and your table users has only 5 fields, right?

Comment: yes image field is longblog and yes table has 5 fields.

Comment: You should hash with something stronger then md5 and use salts.

Answer (score 4):

You get the image filename into a variable called `$filename`, but in your SQL statement you try to insert it from a variable called `$image`.

You should uncomment the `use strict` line in your program and fix the problems that it shows you.